# How can we call Authentication means Login/ Sign Up api's in react-native using Magento2

Tags: magento, react-native, magento2

I am developing sample mobile app. I Know how to call REST API's , but i don't know how to setUp Magneto 2  and Login/ Sign Up Api's

I am using one sample api that api  from got response one token . after i got token what should i do , i don't know exactly.

Please make sure any possibilities for react-native with Magneto 2 authentication

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to get customer token by sending email and password to the

```
POST /V1/integration/customer/token
```

then you can use customer-related endpoints like

```
GET /V1/customers/me
```

you have to add customer token to the request header

```
'Authorization': 'Bearer ${customerToken}',
```

Here is Magento 2 [docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html)

And also you can have a look my open source [React Native Magento](https://github.com/troublediehard/magento-react-native) project